# How to use a javascript variable in an angular component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have some javascript code (which I am using for mapbox) in my .ts file for an angular component. I wish to use a variable from that javascript code (polygonCoordinates[]) in my typescript code but I am not sure how to. I have included the ngOnInit() part of my code.

I already tried using it directly from the javascript part but that did not work. Any help would be appreciated as I am new to this.

```
  ngOnInit() {

    let script = this.renderer2.createElement('script');
    script.type = `application/javascript`;
    script.text = `
          var polygonCoordinates = [];   
          //and then there's some code for mapbox
        });
    `;
    this.renderer2.appendChild(this.document.body, script);

}
```

Comment: Why would you append a script tag to the page to create a variable/ add code? Why not just execute code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variable `polygonCoordinates` is declared in the global scope that is accessible from anywhere as `window.polygonCoordinates`

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'application/javascript';
script.text = "var polygonCoordinates  = 'hello'";
document.head.appendChild(script);

// from anywhere
console.log(window.polygonCoordinates) //hello
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your reply. However, console.log(window.polygonCoordinates) gives me this error message: Property 'polygonCoordinates' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'

Comment: it looks like a compile time issue from typescript. try (window as any).polygonCoordinates

Comment: Sorry, I am just new to it. Thank you so much. That worked!

Answer (score 0):

at first please refer type of var, like : `studentUpdateDetails:any = [];`
then use it like : `this.studentUpdateDetails = [{"key":"value"},{"key":"value"},{"key":"value"},{"key":"value"}]`